# How do you call a theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a theorem in complex analysis stating:

If we have a holomorphic function $f: U \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and if it is continuous in open nonempty subset $V \subset U$ , then it is constant in whole of $U$.

Now, what I do not know is how is this theorem called in English language and I am not fancy looking up 100 pages in some complex analysis book just for that answer. Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mean "if it is CONSTANT in open nonempty subset"?

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name. IIRC it is usually taken to be a corollary of the identity theorem.

Answer (score 3):

This theorem is generally referred to as the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) (assuming that you mean for $f$ to be constant on $V$, not continuous).  Or, at the very least, it is an immediate corollary of the Identity Theorem, hence it is "not wrong" to call it the Identity Theorem if you are invoking the result.

Comment: And there's the quibble that $U$ must be _connected_... :)